# How to schedule a message in our application to WhatsApp?

Tags: android, whatsapp

I would like to send, schedule text messages in WhatsApp from my application. Is it possible to do that?

Currently, I can open WhatsApp using this code

```
Intent i=getpackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(i);
```

However, is it possible to schedule a message from our application to WhatsApp?

Comment: May be no, whats is not allowing, you need to manually post the message.

Comment: Thank you for Quick response Panakj,In google Pay store we have some whatsapp schedulers. i would like to do like that

Comment: Can you please share that app link, let me check it, Till yet as i know using intent u can pass message and start whats app but you need to manually send message, what is is officially not allow to send message out side, some other person are sending message via web they have log in in web and using script they are sending messages

Comment: This is the link plese go through it.https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=infinitylabs.com.whatsappscheduler&hl=en

Comment: @ProgramingWorld Please check my solution and let me know in case of concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `AlarmManager` for schedule any task for the future..
In your `Activity/Fragment` use this lines of code for schedule any task:-

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(AlaramClass.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlaramClass.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, "SPECIFY_YOUR_TIME_HERE_TO_SCHEDULE_TASK", pendingIntent);
```

And than create the receiver to receive future task

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent i=getpackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

And do not forget the entry for Receiver  inside the **Manifest** (inside the <**application**>.....<**/application**>)

```
          <receiver
            android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
            android:exported="true" >
        </receiver>
```

And u need to add the **WAKE_LOCK** permission for it like below:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 1):

> But i would like to know how to schedule message from our application to what'sapp

No, there is no such API till now

Comment: Thank you for u r quick response darish,Without API can we send what'sapp message from our application.

Comment: you can share text, image, or video into whatsapp via intent