# How to perform actions on time basis in android?

Tags: android, android-background

In my application I want the user to auto log out after 10 PM and can login after 10 AM only .Now I am picking the current time but I don't know how to this for my scenario ,If the application is not in background then also it should work(I should work in background) .

Comment: You can use AlarmManager to schedule this sort of stuff https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example

Comment: when the user open's your application inside onCreate check the current time if it's between 10 PM to 10 AM close the application and show a Toast message. No need to use any kind of scheduler

Comment: Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43062070/3946958 .. It will help u..

Comment: @billynomates thank you ,It helped !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AlarmManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example) to schedule repeating actions.
Something like this:

`myAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute`

Comment: I have attempted the code ...Please go through the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44963723/alarmmanager-not-invoking-the-task/44963756#44963756

Answer (score 1):

Download the Sample by google itself, which gives all 3 types of repeating tasks example.

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned in comments

Check the time when user open the app, and if he should be logged out perform the logout and perform to the LogIn activity you probably implemented.

If I misunderstood something, let me know.

If you started coding this behaviour, you can provide some code snippets

Comment: I want to maintain one flag value as per the timing ,as per flag value I have some other work also ,So I want the time checker kind of thing in background mode .

Comment: So, like when the application is off? Or like an AsyncTask that execute in background ?

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to see what I mean