# AlarmManager not invoking the task?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to execute a auto-logout after 10 PM everyday in my application, for that that I have implemented a AlarmManager task but it is not invoking .For testing purpose I have given the other timing .(e.g

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,15);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,59);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,30);
```

)
AlarmManager Code:

```
 sign_in_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hideKeyboard(LoginActivity.this);
                //implementation of auto logout
                checkSuiteSession = new CheckSuiteSession(getApplicationContext());
                checkSuiteSession.check_attendance_flag("true");
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,15);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,59);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,30);
                Intent autoLogoutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AutoLogoutRecevier.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,autoLogoutIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
```

My broadcast receiver class :

```
public class AutoLogoutRecevier extends BroadcastReceiver {
    CheckSuiteSession checkSuiteSession;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        checkSuiteSession = new CheckSuiteSession(context);
        //calling logout function
        checkSuiteSession.logoutUser();
        Log.d("LOGOUT","auto logout executed");
        checkSuiteSession.check_attendance_flag("false");


    }
}
```

My manifest file (I have added the following permission) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fresherguru.checksuite">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver android:name=".autoLogoutReceiver.AutoLogoutRecevier">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".autoLogoutReceiver.ActivateLogin">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".autoLogoutReceiver.ChangeDialogStatus"
            android:process=":remote"/>
        <receiver android:name=".autoLogoutReceiver.ScreenUnlockReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />-->
            </intent-filter>
            </receiver>


        <receiver android:name=".autoLogoutReceiver.DeviceBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".service.CallHandleAlarmService"
            android:enabled="true"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".home.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".home.HomeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


        <activity
            android:name=".home.CheckSuiteForm"
            />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post your manifest.

Comment: @DavidWasser I have added the complete manifest ,Please check !!

Comment: Manifest looks OK. Try using `AlarmManager.set()` or `setExact()` instead of `setRepeating()` to see if you can get the alarm to fire at least once. Also, add logging and output the milliseconds you use for the alarm time and check if the value is as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Change and set right time for *10 PM* in your `Calendar` object:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,21);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,59);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,59);
```

Comment: For testing purpose I have given that timing (Yesterday I was checking with the current timing whether the code is executing or not).

Answer (score 0):

Did you put

`<receiver android:name=".AutoLogoutRecevier" />`

in your manifest?

Comment: ya I have added .